# How do I record a split transaction in a QIF manually?

Tags: gnucash, qif

I am trying to write a QIF file manually so I can learn to convert csv files to QIF myself without a third party app on Linux.

I am having difficulty understanding how to record a split transaction.

The following is an example transaction where we receive income, $1000.  It must be split between health care deduction, taxes, and deposit to checking.  This is what I have, but GNU Cash doesnt properly import it.  How can I fix this?  What should a split transaction look like in a qif file?

```
!Type:Bank
D02/08/2019
T1000.0
SAssets:Current Assets:Checking
$800
SExpenses:Taxes
$100.0
SExpenses:Insurance:Health Insurance
$100.0
PD02/08/2019 Pay Check
LIncome:Company:Salary
^
```

Comment: Can you export a QIF file from gnucash as an example?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep "copy a working example" is older than humanity... :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a real-wold QIF split transaction exported from Quicken 2016, and successfully imported into GnuCash:

```
D7/ 2'15
U-158.32
T-158.32
CX
PAmazon Marketplace Seattle Wa
Moffice stuff / roku
LHousehold:Office Related
SHousehold:Office Related/Deductable Expense
EPens & Pads
$-22.89
SAuto & Transport:Service & Parts
EAuto emergency escape tool
$-16.23
SHousehold:Electronics
ERoku 3 & holder
$-119.20
^
```

Consider including an M line for the transaction and S lines for each split even if they are empty. I've had problems importing a file the worked once I made that change.

Comment: There's an example split QIF file seen here [qif-split, python code](https://github.com/ebridges/qif-split), and here as well [microsoft money sample export](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicken_Interchange_Format#Sample_Account_Export)